# Build and install apache mod_proxy with custom PROXY_WORKER_MAX_NAME_SIZE

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, mod-proxy

I am having a problem with a vhost (php-fpm/apache) config. It throws the error below:

```
name ProxyPass worker name (unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/site/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs) too long...
```

I am aware that I can solve it easily with a symbolic link or just by removing the unix socket or the fgcid part.

But I am thinking of another way. I would like to know if it's possible to build the `mod_proxy` module with `apxs`, set the `PROXY_WORKER_MAX_NAME_SIZE` to something greater than 96 characters and then installing it to my Apache 2.4.

How can I do that?

Comment: i added sources link and offcial build link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Build apache**

download apache 2.4.x + apr + apr_util

> Build apr & apr_include (./configure & make) to create the .h
>   Copy apr/include/* in apache2.4/include
>   Copy apr_util/include/* in apache2.4/include
>   Copy apache2/os/unix/os.h in apache2.4/include (for linux build)

Build apache:

```
./configure --enable-so --with-included-apr --includedir=/home/remy/Bureau/build_2.4.7/apache2/include/ --with-apache=/home/remy/Bureau/build_2.4.7/apache2/
Make
```

Build apache module (with gcc):

```
gcc -fPIC -DSHARED_MODULE -I/home/frogg/Bureau/build/apache2  -I/home/frogg/Bureau/build/apache2/include/-c mod_proxy.h
```

then create the so file to be used with apache

```
touch mod_proxy.so
ld -Bshareable -o mod_proxy.so mod_proxy.o
```

put the .so file in your apache module enabled folder (or available and then a2enmod ..)

restart apache and it sould be ok

to change the max size go to `mod_proxy.h:305` (line 305)
and change 96 by the value you want:
`#define PROXY_WORKER_MAX_NAME_SIZE      96`

**sources**

The apache sources are avaible here:

- https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi
- https://github.com/apache/httpd

The apache APR sources are avaible here:

- https://apr.apache.org/download.cgi

Official install doc

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/install.html

Comment: I will get apr & apr_utils from here https://apr.apache.org/download.cgi 
and apache source from here https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache24?

Comment: normaly, i will check tomorow my links i don't have them available there

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to update your apache version

source : https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/43551

```
The bug was reported to apache in 2012 https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53218 and the issue is marked as resolved simple by making the size to 256.
```

Comment: It seems that in apache >=2.4.9 versions I can use 
<FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
</FilesMatch>

And ignore completely the ProxyPassMatch, according to symfony docs  (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#php-fpm-with-apache-2-2)

Comment: you can even use `RewriteRule (.*) fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/$1 [P]` if you dont want to use proxypass